# paypal web reference

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Hi I have a site in asp.net and I use paypal sandboox what I need to do now ? (if I need to change the web referfnce what is url ?  )
at sandbox is Works fine . 
 Thanks

Comment: Are you asking what would be the URL for the production transaction PayPal API versus the Sandbox transaction testing API?

Comment: what paypal "product" are you using?  There are 4 - 5 different ways to process transactions through paypal.

Comment: I use this url to the send box "https://api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/" and what about the web  referfnce I see there sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Switch from the sandbox URL https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to the live site URL https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

The above URL is for Paypal instant payment notification (IPN) service.
For other services, following link lists the URLs for both Paypal and PayPal Sandbox.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_testing_SBOverview

Comment: its not that simple there are several different API URLs that could be used depending on the service and features. for example if NVP and websites payment pro is being used the URL would look more like this: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp but if it's not those services then it would be a different URL. We need to know the PayPal service in question first.

Comment: @a.stgeorge: Yes I assumed... Sorry for that...!!